# Convert - 9 November 2000 to 9/11/2000

Tags: mysql, date, select, date-format

I have a text representing date (mysql database Date table) i want to convert it to custom format as MM-dd-YYYY

Eg. Convert from -  9 November 2000  to 9/11/2000

also suggest me sort with date in PHPMYADMIN

Regards,
Arjun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('9 November 2000', '%e %M %Y'), '%e/%c/%Y');
```

Check out this link for [**MYSQL Datetime Functions**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: i have date stored in data base as

Comment: @user2573165 what is the format of date which you have stored in database

Answer (score 1):

use query like

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('9 November 2000', '%e %M %Y'), '%e/%c/%Y')
```

and for sorting use indexing or try using order by

Answer (score 1):

you can use sql syntax like this to create custom date format

```
 DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y') --> 07-11-2013
 DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d %b %y') --> 11 Jul 13
 DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m/%d/%Y') --> 07/11/2013
```

To use sort in PHPMyAdmin, you can use mysql query such as

```
 SELECT * from TABLE_NAME order by DATE_COLUMN_NAME
```

Hope it helps! Good luck!